# How to control each channel's volume when audio's channel has more than 2 in Directshow?

Tags: audio, directshow, volume, channel

In IBasicAudio people can only control volume and balance, this 2 function can not controll each channels volume if they are more than 2.

Is there any way to do that in directshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is not a problem at all, forget about it, the volume sounds same no matter filter graph use 1 or more instances.

Answer (score 0):

`IBasicAudio` controls volume of entire audio stream, and typical implementations control hardware levels, without data modification. If you need to adjust individual channel volume, you need to convert data to PCM and modify the data (multiply the sample values by a factor of interest).

Comment: Thank for answering the question. While your solution is not quite right. because when we get sample, its a big data chunk, you basicly change volume to the whole data and it may not be correct when you control the volume in realtime, it will still play with previous volume. 

what i mean is that there will be big delay to control volume in this way, people have to control volume through ibasicaudio

So my solution is to splitt all channels into multiple stereo pair and control each volume through change volume and balance

Comment: You certainly want to control volume on hardware, or at the latest step so that delay is minimal. However all these method don't offer you per-channel control over volume. If you modify the data yourself, the latency might be more or less - it's up to you how you manage it, it does not necessarily have to be "big delay". Splitting between renderers definitely works out as long as you trust mixer to get everything together. It does not work well with some audio output hardware though, and you definitely cannot route mixed output into file.

Comment: Basically splitting between renderers is not the best solution, it is rather a workaround.